# How to show a hierarchical structure on the axis labels with ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to create a plot like this with ggplot2:
[image: Barplot with hierarchical labels on the x axis]

(I made a small error here that caused not all labels to show up. obviously I do want all labels to show up :) )
However, my Google search didn't turn up anything. The closest I got was with barNest from plotrix, however, I don't like the quality of the graphs that are produced. The ggplot2 ones look a lot better.

In the ideal case, I would have expected to be able to do something like this:
scale_x_discrete("Axis Title", labels=Level1+Level2+Level3)
And then Level1, Level2 and Level3 would have been columns of the data frame that was used in the qplot function.
If I can get this to work, I want to create a function to add this type of functionality to the scales function. Maybe scale_x_hierarchical would be better.
Similar data can be generated with the following code:

```
data <- data.frame(
  Subject = c(rep(1, 48), rep(2, 48), rep(3, 48), rep(4, 48)), 
  month = rep(c(rep(1, 12), rep(4, 12), rep(7, 12), rep(10, 12)), 4), 
  day = rep(c(rep(1, 4), rep(11, 4), rep(21, 4)), 16), 
  hour = rep(c(0, 6, 12, 18), 48), 
  data = rnorm(192))
```

By the way, the image used here is created with Spotfire.

Comment: This is an abomination of a plot and I hope there isn't a way of doing it in ggplot.  (Paraphrasing Hadley's response to another question.)  But seriously, this plot doesn't do it for me.  Use facets instead.

Comment: Are you married to doing it in ggplot2 for some reason?  This looks like a job for base graphics.  It also looks like a good time to rethink how you're plotting your data moreso than what software to use.

Comment: Could you provide us with some data?

Comment: @Andrie: You might think it is an abomination, others really like it. I don't think facets will work with four nested levels? @John: no not married to ggplot2, but I really like the looks and the way it builds up a graph. @Brandon Bertelsen: I have added a bit a R to create a sample data set.

Comment: Can you really fit 192 hour labels into a single row and still have it readable? Each one or two digit number would have to be about the width of each bar.

Comment: @Henry: Obviously, that would mean that the bars would be bigger and the image would be wider. In practice that might eventually mean, that I will need to spilt a graph to get it printed.

Comment: Did you come up with anything? I want to create a similar sort of hierarchy for an axis label in a reasonably different graph, and I'll tell you what I come up with. (I may use barNest; if you know the crazy hacks for reducing clutter in the base graphics, you can make them look much better.)

Comment: @ThomasLevine No, I didn't come up with anything yet, would you be willing to share the crazy hacks if you can make the barNest plots look good?

Answer (score 0):

It's a little different, but the LearnR blog has a [post](http://learnr.wordpress.com/2009/04/29/ggplot2-labelling-data-series-and-adding-a-data-table/) on linking a table to a graph so that it looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's quite difficult to understand what information you want to get out of this data presentation. Also please note that having a column called 'data' in an object called `data` is bad practice. I have renamed the column 'result'.

To achieve a similar effect with ggplot, you can use `facet_wrap` or `facet_grid` formatting properties to achieve a nested effect in general:

```
data %>% 
  mutate(date = map2(month, day, ~ymd(str_c("2023", .x, .y, sep = "-")))) %>% 
  unnest(date) %>% 
  ggplot()+
  geom_bar(aes(x = hour, y = result, 
               fill = as.factor(Subject)), 
           stat = "identity", position = "dodge")+
  labs(x = "Month/Day/Hour", fill = "Subject")+
  facet_wrap(~day(date)+format(date, "%B"), strip.position = "bottom",nrow = 1)+
  theme_bw()+
  theme(
    strip.placement = "outside",
    strip.background.x = element_blank(),
    strip.text.x = element_text(size = 8))
```

[image]

Here I've used `facet_wrap` and specified in the function that I want the labels at the bottom of the plot (`strip.position = "bottom"`). To more closely match the figure above, I've also specified that I want the facets to only plot in one row (`nrow = 1`).

The arguments in `theme()` control the placement of the facet strip text outside of the axis, the fill. and the text size.